# Tailwind on click show data

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

i am showing sub menu by on Hover in tailwind css,

How can i achieve exact same functionality by doing onclick event instead of on hover.

[**DEMO**](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EYQzLfUdGH)

**CODE:**

```
<div class="group">
 <span class="font-bold text-gray-700"> Admission</span>
 <div class=" hidden group-hover:block  bg-white  w-auto">
  
<div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200 ">
  Admission Process
</div>
<div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200"">
  option 1
</div>
<div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200"">
  option 2
</div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

is there a way to do using only tailwind css or js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query your dropdown with JavaScript and then add listener to `click` event.

```js
const dropdownButton = document.querySelector("#dropdown");
const dropdownList = document.querySelector("#dropdown + div.hidden");

dropdownButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dropdownList.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="group">
 <span class="font-bold text-gray-700" id="dropdown">Admission</span>
 <div class=" hidden group-hover:block  bg-white  w-auto">
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200 ">
    Admission Process
  </div>
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200">
    option 1
  </div>
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200">
    option 2
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

#### Multiple dropdowns

If you want to have one code for many dropdowns, you could replace `dropdown` id with css class, like this (I assume that structure for every dropdown will be the same):

```html
<div class="group dropdown">
 <span class="font-bold text-gray-700">Admission</span>
 <div class=" hidden group-hover:block  bg-white  w-auto">
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200 ">
    Admission Process
  </div>
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200">
    option 1
  </div>
  <div class="p-3 hover:bg-gray-200">
    option 2
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

And then query & loop over every dropdown to add event listeners:

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
  dropdown.querySelector('span').addEventListener("click", () => {
    dropdown.querySelector('span + div').classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: what if have more then one menu?

Comment: Check the update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

**1st Option: Using data-dropdown-toggle attribute**

If you want to show a dropdown menu when click on an element, make sure that you add the the data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownId" data attribute to the element that will toggle the dropdown menu.

Check the Example: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/dropdowns/

**2nd Option: Using @click hide and show option**

Check the Example: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/tailwind-css-dropdown-menu-85681515

Comment: Note that the first option requires `flowbite.js` and the second `alpine.js`. You can do that easily with pure javascript, there are not needed libraries for a such simple use case.